# Linq nested or inner query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

Suppose I have a list of employees and each employee has several projects. I can get a given employee using:

```
var employee = employees.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == "id");
```

But how can I filter also project for the employee?

For example:

```
var employee = list
  .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Key == employeeKey && 
                        x.Projects.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Key == projectKey));
```

Comment: Do projects in employees entity or different entity ?

Comment: Do you want to get a employee filtered by id and all the the projects of that employee filtered by their id? Or just and employee filtered by `employee.Id` *and* `Project.Id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to filter down the `Projects` after getting the Employee you can use a `.Select()`.

```
var result = employees.Where(e => e.Id == id).Select(e => new Employee
            {
                Id = e.Id,
                Projects = e.Projects.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Key == projectKey)
            }).SingleOrDefault();
```

So you can get the data you need in one step, but you have to assign the properties by yourself.

Another way is to first get your `Employee` and then filter down the projects, like BoredomOverload suggested:

```
var employee = employees.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id== "id");
employee.Projects = employee.Projects.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Key == projectKey);
```

Either way you get the employee and the Projects of that Employee filtered.

Answer (score 0):

`var employee = employees.SingleOrDefault(
                        x => x.Id.Equals("id") && x.project.Equals("project")
                                         );`

Comment: I need to filter the project by Id

Comment: Simply use `x.project.Id == id` after &&

Answer (score 0):

Use `Any()` LINQ method like

```
var employee = employees.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id== "id" && x.Projects.Any(p => p.Id == "Id"));
```

Moreover, You are filtering based on employee ID `x.Id== "id"` and mostly that employee ID would a primary key (Unique in nature) and in such case filtering just by `Id` would be much enough I believe

Comment: The `.ToList()` is redundant since you are only getting one Employee.

Answer (score 0):

SingleOrDefault returns the object if found or null. So, in your case, it returns all employees because you are not testing anything. You just said if the project is there then return it.

Use Any instead which will return a boolean value if exist or not:

```
var employee = list.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Key == customerKey && x.Projects.Any(p => p.Key == projectKey));
```

If you need to filter if he has only one project with the specific key:

```
var employee = list.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Key == customerKey && x.Projects.Count(p => p.Key == projectKey) == 1);
```

You can also achieve it with SingleOrDefault but test the value with null:

```
var employee = list.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Key == customerKey && x.Projects.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Key == projectKey) != null);
```

If you want the return type to be more specific then use the select.

If it didn't work, try to add "include" to the list:

```
list.Include("Projects").... the rest of the query
```